# how to display two values in a row of listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am displaying the details in a list view from the database with this code:

```
ListView lv=getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry, R.id.animalName, listvalues);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the **listvalues** here is an arraylist...

**getiing the values in an arraylist**:

```
    WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());           
        ArrayList<String> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);
```

**getListDetails()** :

```
public List<String[]> getListDetails(String rowid)
{
    openOrCreateDatabase();
    createAllValuesTable();

    List<String[]> recentdata=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    //String selectQuery="select * from allvaluestable where ROWID="+rowid;
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from allvaluestable where _id ='"+rowid+"'", null);
    String[] values = null;
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToLast();

        while (c.isBeforeFirst() != true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 280; i++) {
                values[i]=c.getString(i);
                System.out.println("Db print**" + recentdata.get(i));
            }
            c.moveToPrevious();
        }
        recentdata.add(values);
        c.close();
    } else {
        recentdata.add(values);
    }
    closeDatabase();

    return recentdata;
}
```

is it possible to display two items in each row of the listview???
 as in like i want to display the attribute name and the value of that attribute like 
first name-abc
middlename-xyz
lastname-pqr
how do i do that???
and wat changes do i have to make in the xml file?? please let me know that too!!
please help! thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/..

Comment: the code is nice and easy to understand but icant seem to figure out how do i use my arraylists in place of those strings in the adapter???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a custom adapter and override getView()

```
public class AdapterWine extends ArrayAdapter<Wine> {

private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
List<Wine> wines;
List<Wine> originalValues;

List<Wine> arrayList;      

public AdapterWine(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Wine> wines) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, wines);

    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.wines = wines;
    this.originalValues = wines; 
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return wines.size();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iconImg = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconImg);
        holder.topText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.topText);
        holder.bottomText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Wine wine = wines.get(position);

    switch(wine.getType()) {

        case blanc:
            holder.iconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wineiconwhite);
            break;

        case rouge:
            holder.iconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wineiconrouge);
            break;

        case rose:
            holder.iconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wineiconrose);
            break;
    }

    holder.topText.setText(wine.getName());
    holder.bottomText.setText(wine.getCepage()+" - "+wine.getMillesime());

    return row;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconImg;
    TextView topText, bottomText;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter and override getView()

[AndroidListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

place two TextViews in your view_animal_entry.xml, override getView in your adapter and set those two TextViews

Answer (score 0):

You can check this guide I wrote on how to create a custom adapter from a ArrayList:

[Multi-clickable ListView](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)

Comment: Yes, indeed. You should past it as part of the Activity code.

Answer (score 0):

create a new xml file in res/layout/ folder with two `TextView`s inside a `LinearLayout` and pass this layout's id as the 2nd argument in the `ArrayAdapter` contructor. That should do the trick

Comment: and how do u suggest i put it in the array adapter....like this: `ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry, {R.id.animalName, R.id.viewname}, listvalues)`........is this syntax correct???

Answer (score 0):

Create a Adapter for the listView and override a getView() function. In getView() function you have to create two TextView every time when it is called automatically and put the two values in them you want to display.

```
        public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
        {

               private Context context;
               private View listView; 
               List<String> name;

        public ListViewAdapter (Context c, List<String> name,View v) 
        {
               context = c;
               this.listView = listView;
               this.name = name;
        } 

        public int getCount() {
           return name.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
                 LinearLayout row=new LinearLayout(context);

         TextView name=new TextView(context);
         name.setText(//firstName);
         name.setTextSize(18);
         name.setTextColor(theme.getItemColorGrid());

         TextView mname=new TextView(context);
         mname.setText(//middleName);
         mname.setTextSize(18);
         mname.setTextColor(theme.getItemColorGrid());

         TextView lname=new TextView(context);
         lname.setText(//lastName);
         lname.setTextSize(18);
         lname.setTextColor(theme.getItemColorGrid());

                 row.addView(fname);
                 row.addView(mname);
                 row.addView(lname);

                 return row;

}

     //Calling the adapter

              ListView listView=new ListView(ActivityMName.this);
              listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(ActivityName.this,listNames,listView);
```

You need to find the substring of the Name as first name, middlename, last name. and put them in textview.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());           
List<String[]> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);

for (String[] name : listvalues) {

     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                 map.put("firstname", name[0]);
                                 map.put("middlename", name[1]); 
                                 mylist.add(map);

            // Keys used in Hashmap
                     String[] from1 = {"firstname", "middlename"};

                        // Ids of views in listview_layout
                   int[] to1 = { R.id.one, R.id.two};

                // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item

   SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist, R.layout.row1, from1, to1);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Hope this will give you some solution.  For more [reference](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

Comment: it is showing a type mismatch error in the **for** line for listvalues and name..

Comment: Use that class name instead of String.

Comment: Otherwise use List<String[]> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);
instead of ArrayList<String> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);

Comment: now when i change my function getListDetails also accordingly it shows nullpointerexception.....see my edit above

Comment: ok but you didn't change this one  List<String[]> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);

 instead of ArrayList<String> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);

Comment: yes i did change it to ` List<String[]> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);`

Comment: At where did u get this NullPointerException?

Comment: at  this line `List<String[]> listvalues=way.getListDetails(appno);`...and this line `values[i]=c.getString(i);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29534/discussion-between-nirmal-and-shivani)